# Is there a way to mathematically prove the change in XIRR

Tags: excel, math, finance

For example, if a Life-To-Date XIRR through June was Y percent, and then through September is Z percent, is there a way to mathematically prove the change in life-to-date XIRR just by looking at the July-Sep cashflows?

Comment: Not really programming related, try the [math.se] site.